# mysql best way to count orders ordered by status

Tags: php, mysql

For my panel I update my "status-buttons" with count-numbers.

F.e. New 2, backorder 5, cancelled 3, shipped 201

In the back, I now count them like this:

```
while($status = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
   $countSQL = $mysqli->query("SELECT id FROM orders WHERE status=".$status['id']." AND user=".$user);
   $countStatus = mysqli_num_rows($countSQL);
   // etc...
}
```

I know... "Use prepared statements"... I will, in the updated version of my script :-)

But is there an easier way to get all the orders from that specific user and then just receive the amount per "status"?

I already tested the below, but in the average, the difference is 0.000024 vs 0.000034.
So it is faster, but I think (and hope) there is a better way?

```
SELECT 
        SUM( CASE WHEN status = '1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS one, 
        SUM( CASE WHEN status = '2' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS two, 
        SUM( CASE WHEN status = '3' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS three, 
        SUM( CASE WHEN status = '4' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS four, 
        SUM( CASE WHEN status = '5' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS five, 
        SUM( CASE WHEN status = '6' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS six, 
        SUM( CASE WHEN status = '7' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS seven, 
        SUM( CASE WHEN status = '8' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS eight, 
        SUM( CASE WHEN status = '9' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS nine, 
        SUM( CASE WHEN status = '10' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS ten, 
        SUM( CASE WHEN status = '11' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS eleven 
FROM orders 
WHERE user=$user
```

Also, the upper way is not that usefull when there would be new statusses available (12,13,...).

Comment: Have you thought of just using `GROUP BY status`?

Comment: Can you explain more your inputs and desired output?

Comment: The first executes a query within a loop, which will not scale well. The second is very hard-coded, what if you get a status of 12, 13 or 14? Just count the rows with a `GROUP BY status`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `group by` when status value is dynamic

```
SELECT id, status, count(id) as total FROM orders WHERE user='userid' GROUP by status
```

Comment: That is much better. 
Result for this query = 0.000017sec
my "sum" - query = 0.000024sec
first (active- query = 0.000038sec